# Batch normalize audio volume on .ogg-files

Tags: software-recommendation, sound

Are there any simple tools to normalize an .ogg-library of 10'000+ songs so that the volume is the same throughout all songs?

Terminal or GUI doesn't matter, it only need to be simple.

One caveat though, I don't want soft interludes/intermissions and ballads blown out of proportion.

Preferably the process should find the overall gain of the album (I have all my CD's ripped into separate folders) and normalize the level thereafter.

Answer (score 3):

There's a tool in the repositories called `EasyMP3Gain` that works on Vorbis files. It will go Album gain adjustments as well as track adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a tool in the repositories called normalise-audio which will do it .It is somewhat faster than easymp3gain

Answer (score 1):

`normalize-ogg` is a command line program included in the `normalize-audio` package. The files will be re-encoded, not just tagged with replay gain information.

To install, go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get install normalize-audio
```

To use, type:

```
normalize-ogg *.ogg
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Your answer could be improved a lot by including how to install and an example on how to use normalize-ogg. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [QtGain[image: Install QtGain]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/qtgain)

```
sudo apt-get install qtgain
```